# Read a .ipynb file in Azure Databricks Repos

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read a .ipynb file into the repos of Azure Databricks, but encountering the following error:

[error 95](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwwl1.png)

Interestingly, other file types like xlsx seem to work just fine:

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BF3f.png)

I've already tried several approaches to resolve it, including:

- Using both the .ipynb extension in the file path and trying without it.
- Changing the file permissions using chmod.
- Copying the file to the tmp/ folder (when the file is in dbfs, I tried copying it to tmp/).
- Attempting to use other libraries such as io and pathlib.
- Copying the file from repos to dbfs.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to achieve the desired outcome, which is to execute the following action as depicted in the image below:

[i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhwLB.png)

**Desired Action**

My suspicion is that Azure Databricks might be denying the read operation for security reasons.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notebooks aren't exposed to the Workspace File System (WSFS). It's kind of design decision.  If you need to obtain notebook's source code, then you can use [Databricks Python SDK](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/sdk-python.html) (recomemnded) or [Export Workspace object REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/workspace/export) (cumbersome).

```py
import base64

import databricks.sdk
from databricks.sdk.service.workspace import ImportFormat

w = databricks.sdk.WorkspaceClient()
notebook = w.workspace.export("/Repos/..../notebook", 
   format=ImportFormat.JUPYTER)
ipynb = base64.decodebytes(notebook.content.encode('ascii')).decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: I tried the 2 items that you gave me, can you explain better? 

With the sdk, tried to export and import using class WorkspaceExt. And with REST API too.

The sdk works, but, the thing is, the sdk copy the file from repos to workspace and then the error occured again.

Comment: I've added example - I'm not sure if you used the correct APIs