# How to Read Python .py file code from azure databricks workspace

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

How to Read Python .py file code from azure data bricks workspace?
I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the python files using fernet library I have the source code in data bricks workspace, I wanted to read that source code in python, I used below code:

```
with open('/Users/abc@gmail.com/Encrypt_Decrypt_POS/Sample.ipynb','r') as f_read:
file_data = f_read.read()
```

But I am getting below error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/abc@gmail.com/Encrypt_Decrypt_POS/Sample
```

Comment: Do you want to read the code to execute it or for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access files in the workspace, you need to prefix the path with `/Workspace` and you need to have a specific DBR version (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/workspace#--enabling-workspace-files)) - you can just click right on the file in the new UI and select (Copy Path).  But it's not applicable to the notebooks as it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725412/read-a-ipynb-file-in-azure-databricks-repos/76730717#76730717), together with workaround.

```py
with open('/Workspace/Users/abc@gmail.com/Encrypt_Decrypt_POS/Sample.ipynb','r') as f_read:
file_data = f_read.read()
```

But it looks like that you want to include the code for reuse in another notebook - in this case you can just include notebooks content using the `%run` command, like this (you don't need to specify a file extension for notebooks):

```
%run /Users/abc@gmail.com/Encrypt_Decrypt_POS/Sample
```

Comment: I am using databricks 10.4, it seems that all these methods like adding `file:` prefix or `dbfs:` prefix or using no prefix for file under the workspace do not work. The file path itself is already like `/Workspace/path/to/my/file` (copied via `copy --> Full path`).

Comment: Support for workspace files was added in 11.3

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the same issue with data in databricks workspace with below code:

```
with  open('/FileStore/tables/Notebook_1.ipynb','r') as f_read: 
   file_data = f_read.read()
```

I got the same error:

[image]

When you are reading data from data bricks workspace you need to use the Databricks File System (DBFS) to access files within the Databricks environment. I modified the file path as mentioned below:

```
/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Notebook_1.ipynb
```

I tried to read data again with above file path as mentioned in the below code:

```
with  open('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Notebook_1.ipynb','r') as f_read:
    file_data = f_read.read()
```

It read the data successfully without any error:

[image]

Comment: Question is about file in the workspace, not on DBFS

Comment: @Bhavani Thanks!!, Any idea how to convert json into .ipynb file