# Databricks list notebook contents in python

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sdk

I'm struggling to list notebook contents in python in the list, I'm able to list all notebooks path in the Workspace, i need contents for each NB, I have to check which mountpoint are usable in the workspace, because I have many active mountpoints

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use that SDK - it's deprecated. Instead, use the [new Databricks Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/) that has a built-in command to list objects recursively.  Plus SDK also supports [unified authentication](https://databricks-sdk-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html), including implicit authentication when code is running in the notebook.

Here is an example from the repository:

```py
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient

w = WorkspaceClient()

# change this 
start_path = f'/Users/{w.current_user.me().user_name}'

names = []
for i in w.workspace.list(start_path, recursive=True):
    names.append(i.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725412/read-a-ipynb-file-in-azure-databricks-repos/76730717#76730717), there is no direct way to get the source code of a Notebook. You need to import it into the workspace using the [Databricks Python SDK](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/sdk-python.html). Retrieving each notebook content using the above method and checking mount points will be a lengthy process. Instead, use the command below to get all the mount points:

```
display(dbutils.fs.mounts())
```

This will retrieve all the mount points in the workspace, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between notebooks and mounts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for this use case. logic

- Iterate all notebooks for given folder
- Read the notebook by using of decoding method
- You can consolidate the list of notebooks based on the string search.

[github](https://github.com/mllearnng/databricks_tools/blob/main/databricks_notebook_string_search.py)

Comment: Question is about listing notebooks, not reading them